# No values on multicombo selection programatically

Tags: combobox, webix

I have implemented a small multicombo where I programatically select all the checkboxes via a button **"All"** present inside the multicombo popup.
Actually, the data of this multicombo comes from the url. Hence, **when I click on "All" it works visually but doesn't show all the selected values neither in the method getValues**.

Here is the snippet : http://webix.com/snippet/0e2b6cc8

Sorry I don't have any open url for test. Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe. Your code seems to works. Here a updated snippet using data loaded from external api : http://webix.com/snippet/240ad127 (and a button to view getValue result)

Comment: Thanks @fabien-michel, though i am facing the issue with my application structure. I'll check it out again.